# Migrating legacy ant project to maven / gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, ant, maven-antrun-plugin

I have a legacy JAVA project and we use Ant to build it. We are planning to keep using ant for building the project but delegate the dependency management to `maven/gradle` without affecting the existing build process.

What might be the best way to move forward - with Maven or with gradle?

Since existing project has it's own structure(which may not conform to standard Maven archtypes), I know might have to make a custom `archtype` if using maven.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48791837/2458858 provides one way to solve it but I am trying to find a standard solution in which I am able to delegate dependency management within the same project rather than a separate project.

Comment: It does not make sense to keep an old build while migrating to another one...Than my question why would like to migrate if you want to stuck with Ant?  Cause if you want to build with Ant than keep your Ant tool...if you want to migrate than do it but not less than the half way which will fail..